# How to collect the pixel from a line drawn over an image?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a grayscale image that I have drawn 4 lines using cv2:

[Steel microstructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16gri.jpg)

But now I need to collect the pixel values along the lines, creating a "line profile", creating four lists with the values from left to write or top to bottom.

How can I do this?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as img

#defines a scale factor
escala=0.7
cinza_esc = cv2.resize(cinza,None,fx=escala,fy=escala,interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

#collect the dimensions of the image
xdim=cinza_esc.shape[1]
ydim=cinza_esc.shape[0]
se=(0,0);ie=(xdim,0);sd=(0,ydim);id=(xdim,ydim)

#line and text attr
cor = (0,0,0) #define a cor (tons de cinza)
fonte = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
tamanho=int(xdim/500)
tipo_lh=cv2.LINE_4

#create the lines
cv2.line(cinza_esc, sd, ie, cor, 2)
cv2.line(cinza_esc, se, id, cor, 2)
cv2.line(cinza_esc, (0,int(ydim/2)), (xdim,int(ydim/2)), cor, 2)
cv2.line(cinza_esc, (int(xdim/2),0), (int(xdim/2),ydim), cor, 2)

#presents image
cv2.imshow("Imagem com as linhas", cinza_esc)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Well the horizontal line would just be the respective row of the image-array, the vertical line the respective column. For the diagonal lines you could have a look into [numpy.diagonal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html?highlight=diagonal#numpy.diagonal)...

Comment: As you haven't provided the code that produces the image it is hard to give proper advide. Depending on the implementation the information might be lost.
Please provide the code together with the expected output.

Comment: I edited the text to provide the code.

Comment: in opencv there is a lineIterator function

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to draw the line at all.

If you use [skimage.draw.line](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.line) it will give you a list of the points on the line.